# Incompatibility between Solr 7.7.1 web admin and Zookeeper 3.5.5

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am used to view the status of Zookeeper in the Solr web admin interface. After upgrading to ZK 3.5.5 from 3.4.13 the Solr web interface are showing an error.

Is there something wrong with my setup or does solr admin 7.7 not work with ZK 3.5?

[image: Not working]
[image: working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apache Solr Reference Guide 7.7 - Setting Up an External ZooKeeper Ensemble](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble.html#setting-up-an-external-zookeeper-ensemble):

> Solr currently uses Apache ZooKeeper v3.4.13.

And according to [SOLR-8346 Upgrade Zookeeper to version 3.5.5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8346) you'd have to upgrade to Solr 8.2 or 9 to use any ZooKeeper 3.5.x version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very good detective work. Its no longer possible to download version 3.4.13 there are a version 3.4.14. I felt for the temptation to upgrade to ZK 3.5.5. The Solr cluster works. But not the admin interface against ZK.

Comment: 3.4.14 should work as minor releases typically have to maintain compatibility within the 3.4.x releases.